# Should virtualization questions be tagged as both virtualbox and vmware?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should `virtualization` questions be tagged as both `virtualbox` and `vmware`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VMWare and VirtualBox are separate products. If specifically asking about one or the other, use the appropriate tag. No need to use both unless they are both relevant to the question. In either case, you would still use the `virtualization` tag as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should not since VMWare is a specific software but Virtualization can be more general like Virtualbox and other virtualization software.